# How can Ionic be setup to render in the iOS style by default?

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2, ionic3

Right now the ionic app renders with android styling by default. Instead of using the `?ionicplatform=ios` param every single time I'd like that to be the default option.

I looked for hints in the `config.xml` as well as the config settings in app.module.ts such as:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(
      MyApp, 
      {
        swipeBackEnabled: true,
        platforms: {
          ios: {
            swipeBackEnabled: true,
            statusbarPadding: false
          }
        }
      }
    ),
```

and was unable to find an elegant way of doing it...Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just need to do this:

*app.module.ts*

```
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
    mode: 'ios'
})
],
```

**Note:** From `@sebaferreras`

> Btw, by setting this config the app will use the ios styles and
>   components even if you run it on an Android device. Please notice
>   that `?ionicplatform=ios` is just used to see how the app looks like when
>   using the browser, but does not affect how the app is built. But
>   setting mode: 'ios' will force the ios mode and apply the ios styles
>   even if you build and create a .apk file.

Comment: Ok, works! Btw, for anyone reading this with the intention to do the opposite, the alternative mode to ios is not android but 'md' // material design

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: Btw @DavidHaddad, by setting this config the app will use the ios styles and components **even if you run it on an Android device**. Please notice that`?ionicplatform=ios` is just used to see how the app looks like when using the browser, but does not affect how the app is built. But setting `mode: 'ios'` will force the ios mode and apply the ios styles even if you build and create a `.apk` file.

Comment: Thanks for the note! There’s an override for the node within platform Android section which sets mode to ‘md’. The reason why the question was asked was to override the styles when the app is seen on the web :-)

Comment: You can use this `CLI` too: `--lab, -l Test your apps on multiple platform types in the browser`

Comment: Thanks @Sampath... I wish I could upvote the answer twice lol

Answer (score 14):

in index.html just define `mode` (this is not recommended).

For iOS

```
<html lang="en" mode="ios">
```

For android

```
<html lang="en" mode="md">
```

Please just modify the mode in IonicModule (ios/md)

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
    mode: 'ios'
  })
],
```

Comment: this one save me. ionic documentation tell us to use class="ios". which is should be mode="ios". thank you !

Answer (score 11):

Using `@ionic/react` this is how you go:

```js
import {setupConfig} from '@ionic/react'

setupConfig({mode: 'ios'})
```

Alternatively for enforcing Material Design:

```js
setupConfig({mode: 'md'})
```

You could place this code in your main `App.js`/`App.tsx` file.

See also https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/config for further global settings.

Answer (score 5):

For anybody using the new Vue.js support for Ionic, forcing the rendering mode can be achieved by doing this when you import `Vue`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// ios
Vue.use(Ionic, {
  mode: 'ios'
});

// material design
Vue.use(Ionic, {
  mode: 'md'
});
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ionic v6 (React)

Go to your `app.tsx`

- To force Android style (Material Design)

`setupIonicReact({ mode: 'md' })`

- To force iOS style

`setupIonicReact({ mode: 'ios' })`

Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/config

### Ionic v6 (Angular)

Go to your `app.module.ts`

- To force Android style (Material Design)

`imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot({ mode: 'md' }) ]`

- To force iOS style

`imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot({ mode: 'ios' }) ]`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/config

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to Ben Everard's answer, if you are using more recent version of Ionic (4.8.0 in my case)

```
IonicModule.forRoot ->
```

will not accept two parameters. Just drop the first parameter making it as:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({ mode: 'ios' }),
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this in your index.html file

I tried the below html code in ionic 4 and it works

Use the below one for getting styled your apk same as ios.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="plt-iphone plt-ios plt-phablet plt-mobile ios" mode="ios">
```

Use the below one for getting styled your ios app same as android.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="plt-android plt-mobile md" mode="md">
```

Answer (score 1):

For Vue 3 and Ionic 6

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { IonicVue } from "@ionic/vue";


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(IonicVue, {mode: "ios"});
app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Ionic V6 - VUE

```
createApp(App).use(IonicVue, {
  mode: 'ios',
});
```

Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/config