# Ionic 4 Migration: IonicModule changes

Tags: ionic4

I am currently upgrading an Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4,
After 'ionic-angular' changes to '@ionic/angular', The following line of code doesn't work anymore:

`IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{mode: 'md'})`

what is the ionic 4 style for this piece of code to have the same functionality?
I tried

`IonicModule.forRoot({mode: 'md'})`

while my program stop compiling and gives me loader errors.

Comment: This might be similar :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705791/how-can-ionic-be-setup-to-render-in-the-ios-style-by-default/56333901#56333901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `IonicModule.forRoot({mode: 'ios'})` in the `imports` for my app module and it works fine.